# How to create CloudWatch LogGroup with global retention policy?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Whenever I create Cloudwatch LogGroup it creates it with retention period of `never expire`.Is there a way to define retention period of 30 days as default instead of adding it manually during CloudWatch LogGroup creation?

Comment: Check https://medium.com/tensult/manage-aws-cloudwatch-log-group-retention-using-automation-26add478b0c5